# "application blocked by security settings" prevent applets running using oracle SE 7 update 51 on firefox on Linux mint

Tags: java, firefox, plugins, applet

## Background

Complete fresh installation of Oracle Java SDK (32-bit) on Linux. The installation is correct, the plugin is correctly installed.

## Problem

The following error ("Application Blocked by Security Settings") appears when the applet runs inside Firefox:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Setup

Here are the steps I used:

1. Installed Linux mint 16 on VBox:
   `> uname -a
   Linux me-VirtualBox 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:12:00 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`
2. Cleaned all [Java instances](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java).
3. Followed [instructions to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk) jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz on Linux.
4. Verified installation
   `> java -version
   java version "1.7.0_51"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)`
5. Verified plugin:
   `> pwd
   /home/me/.mozilla/plugins
   > ls -l
   total 0
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 46 Jan 22 02:42 libnpjp2.so -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so`
6. Verified [Java plugin](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp):
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
7. Verified Firefox activation:
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
8. Started the Java ControlPanel; set security to Medium:
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
9. Clicked **Apply**.
10. Restarted Firefox.

## Question

How do you change the security settings to allow the applet to run?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this issue. The security settings in the ControlPanel seem to be user specific. Try running it as the user you are actually running your browser as (you are not browsing as root!??) and setting the security level to Medium there. - For me, that did it.

Comment: I was running it as normal user. Not root. I never login as root. I followed the same exact instructions to install as given in the instructions in step 3 in my post. I logged in as normal user. Only one user on the system, which is me. I think setting up Java on Linux is not worth the trouble.

Comment: ...but in your screenshot, you "sudo ./ControlPanel" - so you effectively run it as root... Try without sudo, 'is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought you meant I was running the browser as root. I assumed I needed to be root to run the controlPanel (since it was in /usr/lib/ area). But now I tried it again, and it worked without being a root. I set it down to normal security, applied it. Then started firefox as user again, and now I am able to run the applets !  This is amazing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17):

As an alternative answer, there's a command line to invoke directly the Control Panel, which is `javaws -viewer`, should work for both openJDK and Oracle's JDK (thanks @Nasser for checking the availability in Oracle's JDK)

Same caution to run as the user you need to access permissions with applies.

Comment: thanks. Yes, this worked in Oracle JDK on Linux also. Run as user, OK, it opened the security panel.

Comment: great!, thanks for the tip, I'll update the answer to cover both :)

Answer (score 3):

$pwd
/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_25/bin

./jcontrol

as follow,

java Control Panel --> Security -->  Edit Site list  ,
then  apply, and ok.

Comment: Does jcontrol come with previous versions of JRE?

Comment: thats just awesome and simple

Comment: Very good and simple answer.  I changed security settings using `sudo javaws -viewer` but that must have changed the settings for another version of javaws.  When I followed these instructions and added a new site to the exceptions list the security error went away.

Answer (score 1):

The application that you are running is blocked because the application does not comply with security guidelines implemented in Java 7 Update 51

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Edit Site List** and make it be an exception so that you can run it from the specific website.

Answer (score -2):

Just start your browser with superuser rights, and don't forget to set Java's JRE security to medium.

Comment: That is one of the worst ways to deal with right-based problems and should be avoided at (nearly all) costs.