# Java Web Application not working with JRE1.7 Update 51

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

My Java application works fine with all previous versions of Java apart from JRE1.7 Update 51.
Though i minimized the security level to minimum and added my url to Exception list, the app is still blocked.
Note: My client side jar is signed and server side jar is not signed.
Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Please share error logs or describe the error in detail.

Comment: What is not working? Can you post the error?

Comment: @user1441664, Oracle made it mandatory to sign the applets from update 51. unless you recompile your code according to standards and sign it, it will not work. no alternative solution other than downgrading to older JRE

Comment: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/oracle-java-7-update-51-blocks-unsigned-java-applets-by-default/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279085/application-blocked-by-security-settings-prevent-applets-running-using-oracle
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440354/is-oracle-killing-intranet-applets-on-jre-7-update-51

Comment: @r3ap3r, doesn't need any log. this is well known issue with update 51

Comment: There is no error. After the url is pasted on browser, one pop up has to come for login and that doesn't show up. Though i signed all the jars, its not coming up.